# Internet page not loading, ping not working but host www.example.com return an IP

Tags: snow-leopard, network, dns

Sorry I'm being vague because I don't even know where the problem can be.

Yesterday I was using the internet just fine. Today on the same wifi router and on another 3G connection, I couldn't access any webpages. I tried using those exact same two connections with another laptop and it worked.

I cleared the cache, set up my DNS server to be OpenDNS ones, made sure there was no proxy activated, but no luck. Tested with Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Ping doesn't work. Host does.

I am no networking expert. I'd like help with solving this issue.

Thank you.

Mac OS X 10.6.8 / Firefox & Chrome : Latest

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I fixed it.

A bit of more details first.

dig / nslookup / host commands were working. So I actually had access to internet.

The problem was ping and all Browser using the System resolver that was not working.

I unload then reloaded the /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist with the -w option. And it worked.

Hope it can help,

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific as to how you solved this problem as I seem to be having a similar one. Thanks